# java.util.Comparator.comparing in scala

Tags: scala

The line

```
private val keyComparator = util.Comparator.comparing[(String, String), String]((p: (String, String)) => p._1)
```

produces the error

```
[error] ...: overloaded method value comparing with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: (String, String), _ <: String])java.util.Comparator[(String, String)] <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: (String, String), _ <: String],x$2: java.util.Comparator[_ >: String])java.util.Comparator[(String, String)]
[error]  cannot be applied to (((String, String)) => String)
[error]   private val keyComparator = util.Comparator.comparing[(String, String), String]((p: (String, String)) => p._1)
[error]                                                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 30, 2018 12:05:01 PM
```

If I try to simplify

```
private val keyComparator = util.Comparator.comparing[(String, String), String](_._1)
```

I have another error

```
[error] /home/shu/workspace/kookaburra/src/main/scala/rakuten/kookaburra/util/GrpQuery.scala:41: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$5: <error>) => x$5._1)
[error]   private val keyComparator = util.Comparator.comparing[(String, String), String](_._1)
[error]                                                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 30, 2018 12:24:53 PM
```

What am I doing wrong? Scala 2.12.6. For me it seems like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `java.util.Comparator.comparing` needs a `java.util.function.Function` and you are writing `(p: (String, String)) => p._1`, which is a scala.Function1.

For some reason a scala lambda doesn't compile to java Function unless you ask to do that explicitly.

Otherwise you need to use `java.util.function.Function` or an implicit conversion between java Function and scala Function1.

Here you are an implicit convertion example

```
implicit def sf2jf[T,R](f:(T) => R):java.util.function.Function[T, R] = (t: T) => f(t)
```

Comment: I tried again, with scala 2.12.2 and 2.12.6. If I assign a scala lambda to java Function works, but I can't do that directly with Comparator unless I create a convertion or save the lambda in a variable java Function.